# How to get back conflicts for one file in Git?

Tags: git

I have solved part of the conflicts after merging, but I have figured out that on the current conflict I am keeping the wrong part of code. By mistake there have been done a commit, and (not because of that) I cannot go back with undo until before solving this conflict. Is there a way that I can get back to before previous conflict?

---

More detailed:

- I have solved 3 conflicts in file1
- I have solved 5 conflicts in file2
- I have solved 2 conflicts in file3 and when solving the 3rd conflict I have kept the wrong code part. By mistake I have committed. How to get back to before 3rd conflict in file3 or redo the conflicts in the file3?

Comment: You'll have to check out an old commit and redo the merge.

Comment: This might have been easier to solve if you had `git rerere` turned on before you started resolving conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `git rerere` can sometimes be an option

There are several ways that you could have resolved this. For example, if you had turned on [`git rerere`](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) before you started resolving conflicts, you would have been able to redo the merge from scratch and ***re-apply your conflict resolutions*** automatically with `git rerere`.

### An alternative solution, just for you

*However*, since you're already committed your changes, you can actually reapply your previous conflict resolutions anyways by using `git checkout <revision> -- <file>`, where `<revision>` is the commit sha for your current merged commit:

```bash
# First, let's undo your merge
git reset --hard <previousCommit>

# Next, redo the merge
git merge <branch>

# Next, we'll reapply your previous resolutions
# from the previous merge "PM", for files 1 and 2
git checkout PM -- file1
git checkout PM -- file2

# Next, go ahead and fix the conflicts for file 3...

# When you're done, commit
git commit
```

### Explanation

The command

```
git checkout <revision> -- <file>
```

will checkout the version of `<file>` from `<revision>`. You can find more documentation about this from the [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html).

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you can do.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

This will make your branch's head to point to one previous commit. Then checkout the branch to get the latest changes:

```
git checkout <branch>
```

Then do the merge again.

```
git merge <branch>
```

You can find more information about undoing the merge in the following link.

```
http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html
```