# How to get git conflicts back

Tags: git

I am trying to resolve merge conflicts during cherrypick and I realized I accepted the wrong version of 1 of the files. I want to see the conflicts again and choose the other version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my git merge conflicts back after merging incorrectly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677049/how-do-i-get-my-git-merge-conflicts-back-after-merging-incorrectly)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24687695/7976758

Answer (score 4):

If you have not yet run `git commit` or `git cherry-pick --continue`, and are doing the resolving in the command line, use `git checkout -m` to restore the index to the unmerged state.  For instance (this example uses `git merge` rather than `git cherry-pick` but the process is the same either way):

```
$ git merge $other
[snip some merge output complaining of conflict, e.g., ending with]
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git status
[snip]
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   file
[snip]
$ vim file
[snip]
$ git add file
$ git status
On branch ...
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)
$ git checkout -m file
$ git status
[snip]
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   file
```

If you have already committed, it's too late: you must re-perform the operation.  (Make sure you have `git rerere` disabled.)

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard` to the previous commit and then do the cherry pick again